# Creating a pivot table and finding correlations between books with multiple genres

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics, recommendation-engine

I have a table that is like

```
book_id original_title  tag_id  tag_name
1     The Hunger Games  11305   fantasy
1     The Hunger Games  26771   scifi
1     The Hunger Games  26138   romance
10000       The First World War 14467   historical
10000       The First World War 21689   nonfiction
```

and I want to create a pivot table, to then find books that correlate with each other according to genre. I have already done this using just ratings, but this was relatively simple as each book would have just one rating. Since there are multiple genres for each book, is there a good method of creating this pivot table?

This is with the ultimate purpose of creating a simple recommender system.

Comment: What is the final output that you are looking for?

Comment: Add expected output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
df.pivot(index='original_title',columns='tag_name',values='tag_id')
```